# Canvas force grid cell to be expanded infinitelly

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, canvas

ts:

```
templateStyle = {
      display: 'grid',
      'grid-template-columns': 'calc(25%-10px) calc(25%-10px) calc(25%-10px) calc(25%-10px)',
      'grid-template-rows': '150px auto auto',
      'grid-gap': '10px',
      border: '1px solid #2196F3',
      padding: '10px'
}

widgets = [
   { rowStart: 1, rowEnd: 2, colStart: 1, colEnd: 2, ... },
   { rowStart: 1, rowEnd: 2, colStart: 2, colEnd: 3, ... },
   ...
   { rowStart: 2, rowEnd: 3, colStart: 1, colEnd: 2, ... },
   ...
];

getStyle(widget): object {
  return {    
      position: 'relative',
      'grid-row-start': widget.rowStart,
      'grid-row-end': widget.rowEnd,
      'grid-column-start': widget.colStart,
      'grid-column-end': widget.colEnd,
      'text-align': 'center',
      'vertical-align': 'middle',
      'min-height': card.height + 'px'
  };
}
```

html

```
<div [ngStyle]="templateStyle">
  <div *ngFor="let widget of widgets" [ngStyle]="getStyle(widget)">
     <button (click)="addChart()">Add</button>
     <div *ngIf="If chart added by above button action"
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%"> // widht/height 100% to give all space of the parent
       <canvas style="width: 200px; height: 200px;"
             chartType="pie" 
             [data]="[200, 100]"
             [labels]="['A', 'B']"
             baseChart>
       </canvas>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Eh, the line `style="width: 200px; height: 200px;` is ignored by the canvas and this will force the grid cell to grow infinitelly outside the grid. I'm thinking that this happening because I declared grid-columns using percentages. If I remove the canvas parent style (`width: 100%, height: 100%`), the cell will grow how much space is availaible in the grid.

So I need to calculate column width somehow and give absolute values for grid, and not using percentages as: `grid-template-columns': 'calc(25%-10px) calc(25%-10px) calc(25%-10px) calc(25%-10px)`. I also tried to use `fr`, but have same result. For both cases, I tried to remove canvas and use just a simple container with a background, this will work perfectly, due of this, my opinion is that the canvas force the cell (parent) to be resized each time.

[image: Initial grid widgets]

[image: After adding the pie chart on row 2, column 1]

*I'm really thinking to use d3 charts instead of chartjs if I can't find a solution for this.*

Comment: did you try `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; grid-gap: 10px;`?

Comment: thanks for your answer. It works using `fr` only if I remove the `width (100%)` of canvas parent. I think this can be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
templateStyle = {
 ....
'grid-template-columns': '1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr',
'grid-gap': '10px',
```

with 1fr for each column space will be evenly divided between  4 columns.